# Show models data in TextBlocks

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm need to show data from ViewModel in simple grid which contain labels and textBlock for data. I'm try to bind data to grid and use ElementName to bind grid's DataContext with textBlocks.

Book ViewModel:

```
namespace Books.ViewModels
{
    public class BookViewModel : IViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Book book = new Book();
        private ICommand AddCommand;
        private ICommand RemoveCommand;
        private ICommand ChangeCommand;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public BookViewModel()
        {
            //initialize commands;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return book.Name; }
            set { book.Name = value; }
        }

        public string Authors
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Join(", ", book.Authors.Select(x => x.Name));
            }
            set
            {
                //need to implemented
            }
        }
        public string ISBN
        {
            get { return book.ISBN; }
            set { book.ISBN = value; }
        }
        public int Pages
        {
            get { return book.Pages; }
            set { book.Pages = value; }
        }
        public string Tags
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Join(", ", book.Tags);
            }
            set
            {
                //not implemented
            }
        }
        public int PublicationYear
        {
            get { return book.PublicationYear; }
            set { book.PublicationYear = value; }
        }
        public string House
        {
            get
            {
                return book.House.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                //not implemented 
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddClick
        {
            get
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Add"));
                return AddCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand RemoveClick
        {
            get
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Remove"));
                return RemoveCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand ChangeClick
        {
            get
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Change"));
                return ChangeCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

grid in Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="bookGrid"
              Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Title:"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Author(s):"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="ISBN:"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Pages:"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="Tags:"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Content="Publication Year:"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Content="Publication House:"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=Authors}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=ISBN}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=Pages}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=Tags}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=PublicationYear}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=bookGrid, Path=House}"/>
        </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
bookGrid.DataContext = Manager.books.First();
```

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the TextBlock bindings to something like:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Add a notifier method tho the viewmodel:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And call this method after each property change like:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return book.Name; }
    set
    {
        book.Name = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is fixing binding Source (removing ElementName, `{Binding Name}`) which solvse the problem. DataContext of TextBlock is the same as Grid.DataContext. writing `ElementName` brakes it. adding `INPC` implementation in a viewModel is not relevant in the context of the question

Comment: You're fully right. The `INPC` isn't necessary to fix the problem, I've added it after answering the question because it could help when the DataContext changes.